# Setting a jQuery UI buttons text to false not working in Safari on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

I am building a html menu and I am using jQuery UI to format the buttons.  I want to create an icon only button.  Everything works fine for IE 9, Chrome and Safari on Windows 7.  It also works for Chrome on OS X but not Safari on OS X.

There is an interaction with a Google map that I have on the page.  If I do not create the map the menu will render correctly with the icon only button.  But if I create the map the menu disappears.

The failure occurs when I set the buttons text property to false.  I have tried to do this 2 ways

(1)

```
$("#zoomIn").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-zoomin' }, text: false });
```

(2)

```
$("#zoomIn").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-zoomin' } });
$("#zoomIn").button("option", "text", false);
```

If I dont set this property the menu display correctly but there is text in the button.

The HTML for the button is

```
<button id="zoomIn">xxx</button>
```

I'm including the following files (these are from the jQuery UI demo page)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried including local copies the jQuery libraries.

I'm baffled by this one.  Hopefully someone else has run into this problem and solved it.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your code without setting the text option? Does it work? If so, perhaps a workaround would be to remove the 'xxx' from the button but leave the default text option as true

Comment: @Rob.  Yes I have tried this and it works.  But its not ideal.  If I remove xxx the button losses it height and if I use &nbsp; the button will render but it looks wrong as the icon is not centered in the button.   And just for completeness I tried $("#zoomIn").button("option", "text", true) and this also fails.  So setting the property to either true or false causes the issue.

Comment: Agreed, it's not really a solution. Take a look at the classes added to your menu and it's items by .button(). If the problem is only manifest when you call the map rendering function, it could be a clash of classes; Would be worth a quick search in the source of the map js

Comment: @Rob:  Didn't turn out to be a clash of classes but a style safari didn't like for some reason.  Works fine without a Google map on the page.  Anyway thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked down the issue.

I am using a jQuery UI stylesheet, in which there is a style

```
.ui-button-icon-only .ui-button-text, .ui-button-icons-only 
.ui-button-text { padding: .4em; text-indent: -9999999px; }
```

setting text-indent to -999px; resolves the issue.